# pending timesheet check function with 2 queries not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to get this pendingsubmission function to work properly. The way its suppose to work is if a manager logs into his account and has pending timesheets to review i want somekind of notification to the manager that there are pending timesheets.

Here is my code so far although it only works for the first result (first timesheet, does not get manager for all other timesheets submitted)  i apologize if this is confusing.

```
function pendingsubmissions($loggedInUser) {
        include("table_names.inc");
        global $authenticationManager;

        list($qh, $num) = dbQuery("SELECT uid FROM $TIMES_TABLE WHERE submitstatus=1 OR ot_status=1");
            while ($data = dbResult($qh)) {
                $username = $data['uid'];

        list($qh2,$num2) = dbQuery("SELECT manager FROM $USER_TABLE WHERE username='$username'");
            while ($data2 = dbResult($qh2)) {
                $manager = $data2['manager'];

            if ($loggedInUser == $manager || $authenticationManager->hasClearance(CLEARANCE_ADMINISTRATOR))
                return 1;
            else
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

The first query is to check the database for timesheets that are pending (submit status 1).. if there are any found then the second query is to find out that users manager and then if that users manager is currently logged in, spit out the true value.

The problem is the first query as of now it is showing as follows:

```
uid
---
user1
user1
user1
user2
user2
user2
```

and the second query is only checking for user1 manager name.. doesnt check user2.. can someone help fix this so it checks every user for manager-name

thanks

Comment: do you want the result of query1 to be unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned, you can use `DISTINCT`, or `GROUP BY` a value such as `uid`.

This could also be achieved with a single query. Something like:

```
SELECT manager FROM $USER_TABLE WHERE username IN (SELECT DISTINCT uid FROM $TIMES_TABLE WHERE submitstatus=1 OR ot_status=1)
```

This saves you sending two requests to the database.

You're also overwriting your values each time, instead of:

```
        while ($data = dbResult($qh)) {
            $username = $data['uid'];
```

You will want to do something like:

```
        $usernames = array();
        while ($data = dbResult($qh)) {
            $usernames[] = $data['uid'];
```

Comment: thanks. i tried to use the array for $manager and foreach but still not working.. could you take a quick look? http://pastebin.com/rGytp6n3

Comment: You're still not using `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY`. `$manager` will still potentially contain duplicates. Also, you `foreach` makes little sense as it's going to return either `1` or `0` on it's first iteration.

Comment: i am using distinct that you provided.. i tried it in the SQL and it results manager1 | manager2 as it should. so the query works but i think my problem is the foreach statement

Answer (score 0):

You should write a single query with a JOIN between the 2 tables. At present you are only asking the second query to look for one value!

Also, punctuation is as important in English as it is in programming. Please use apostrophes where they are required. It makes reading your question much easier.